# Происхождение и употребление слова «ковбой»

Tags: этимология, выбор-слов, история

Согласной [статье](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B9) в Википедии, ковбой (от англ. cow — корова, boy — парень) — это человек, который во времена Дикого Запада перегонял скот. Однако почему именно коровы? Сам ковбой-то седлал, как правило, лошадь, а не корову. Помимо всего прочего, у большинства людей при использовании этого слова возникают совсем другие ассоциации: для меня ковбой — это стрелок, бандит или просто охотник за головами. Есть ли какое-нибудь разъяснение насчет этого?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ковбои перегоняли коров или овец с одного пастбища на другое или в места для продажы. Как следствие, им приходилось много путешествовать по диким местам, где могли быть и перестрелки. Да и сами ковбои, пользуясь тем, что вскоре уедут, могли что-нибудь украсть.

В дальнейшем, книги о Диком западе и вестерны героизировали образ ковбоя, но изначально это не более чем кочующий пастух.

Comment: Я сейчас пытаюсь сказать о том, что у современных людей слово *ковбой* ассоциируется с каким-нибудь стрелком, но никак не с пастухом. :)

Comment: Так я и написал, про героизацию образа ковбоя в литературе и фильмах, по которым мы их сейчас воспринимаем. В этом смысле интересно видео Тима Кирби о том, что ковбои, ганста-рэперы и гопники - это по сути один и тот же тип людей. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5ISlBura83A

Comment: Познавательное видео. Спасибо. :)

Comment: Фенимор Купер . "Шпион" . Действие романа разворачивается в период военных действий между США и Великобританией . Это была новая война , уже позднее войны за независимость Соединённых Штатов . В романе есть упоминание о том , что "коубоями" называли полубандитов , которые вели партизанские грабительские действия в тылу США на стороне англичан . ( Другие аналогичные полубандиты , действовавшие на стороне США против англичан , там называются "скинеры" .)